# Oracle Proxy Access

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if we can grant user Proxy Access without granting Insert, delete, update, create or drop tables?

I just want to grant the user access to DB Links which is available only with a Proxy account but want to restrict other operations.

Comment: if I understood your request correctly, you could try (as a workaround until somebody provides you with a better solution) creating a new DB User. Provide that newly created user only with the desired grants (in our case I guess only SELECT) and use your PROXY account to connect to that user. In that way, you will only have SELECT "roles" available for your Proxy account.

Answer (score 0):

If the DB links and tables are owned by User_A, then granting User_B proxy access to User_A (to get to the links) will also allow User_B to create/drop/alter whatever else is in User_A's schema, because User_B effectively *becomes* User_A. You can't prevent that.

A better way to handle granting access to a private database link is to create a view that belongs to User_A that points to the resource in User_A's database link, and then grant SELECT on the view to User_B.

e.g. As USER_A:

```
create database link remote_db connect to remote_user identified by password using 'connect string';
create view remote_view as select * from remote_table@remote_db;
grant select on remote_view to user_b;
```

Then as USER_B:

```
select * from user_a.remote_view;
```

Simply granting other users unfettered access to a db link - either through proxy privileges or public links - exposes a lot more of the remote database's metadata that is generally considered safe or secure. For example, views like ALL_USERS are exposed that could aid in hacking attempts on the remote system by providing a list of all valid userids. It is always best to limit a local user's access to the link to just the specific tables or views they need, as demonstrated here.